# VBA: Is there any difference between the Evaluate(string) and Val(string)

Tags: vba, excel

The `Evaluate()` method, when applied to a `string` returns a `double`.
The `Val()` function also returns a `double`.

```
Evaluate("123") = 123
Val("123") = 123
```

Is there any diffence between the two in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information may be a little out of date, but in [Excel 2003 VBA Programmer's Reference](http://bit.ly/17jfeb8), by Paul Kimmel, he says the following about `Val()`.

> Val is the most common function that we've seen used to convert from
>   strings to numbers. It actually only converts a US-formatted numerical
>   string to a number. All the other string-to-number-conversion
>   functions try to convert the entire string to a number and raise an
>   error if they can't. Val, however, works from left to right until it
>   finds a character that it doesn't recognize as part of a number. Many
>   characters typically found in numbers, such as $ and commas, are
>   enough to stop it from recognizing the number. Val does not recognize
>   US-formatted date strings.

In other words, if Val runs across something which is not a number in the string, it will return all numbers up to that point:

```
debug.? val("100")
 100
debug.? val("100$")
 100
debug.? val("100,000")
 100
```

[Evaluate()](http://bit.ly/1ARXDEC) on the other hand, is used to "convert a Microsoft Excel name to an object or a value", as JLILI Aman states in an earlier answer, and will throw an error if it encounters something in the string which can't be converted to a number:

```
debug.? evaluate("100")
 100 
debug.? evaluate("100$")
Error 2015
debug.? evaluate("100,000")
Error 2015
```

Evaluate is most often used in order to use worksheetfunctions in a macro. It is also sometimes used as shorthand for referring to a range.

Answer (score 1):

1. the Microsoft Excel VAL function accepts a **string** as input and
   returns **the numbers** found in that string.
2. The evaluate converts a *Microsoft Excel name* *(string)* to an **object** or a **value**.

   You've just picked up the wrong example.

> *Microsoft Excel name*:
>
> The following types of names in Microsoft Excel can be used with this
> method: Formulas.
>
> A1-style references. You can use any reference to a
>
> single cell in A1-style notation.
> All references are considered to be absolute references. Ranges. You can use the range, intersect, and union operators (colon, space, and comma, respectively) with references.
>
> Defined names. You can specify any name in the language of
> the macro.
>
> External references. You can use the ! operator to refer to a cell or to a name defined in another workbook — for example, Evaluate( [BOOK1.XLS]Sheet1!A1").
>
> Chart Objects. You can specify any chart object name, such as "Legend", "Plot Area", or "Series 1", to access the properties and methods of that object. For example, Charts("Chart1").Evaluate("Legend").Font.Name returns the name of the font used in the legend.

Answer (score 0):

The Val() function has a use in addition to being a simple conversion function. It will return all numeric characters until it reaches a nonnumeric one. CStr() will return an error if you attempt to convert a string that contains nonnumeric data. For example, Val("123abc") will return the number 123 and Cint("123abc") will return a datatype mismatch error.

Do you mean Eval() if so, this will attempt to carry out any necessary calculations so Eval("2*3") = 6 but Val("2*3") = 2